# How to use SQLite3 with Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to build a simple java program which creates a db file, then a table and inserts dummy values in the table. I found this page http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/index.html and tried out the example given on the page but I am getting the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Test.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that looks like it's a matter of the classpath not being right.

My guess is that you're

If you've put something like

```
java -cp sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test
```

then you probably just need to add the current directory to the classpath:

```
# Windows
java -cp sqlitejdbc.jar-v056;. Test

# Unix
java -cp sqlitejdbc.jar-v056:. Test
```

Having looked at that page, my *guess* is that you used : as the classpath separator, as shown on the page, rather than ; which you need to use if you're on Windows.

Comment: I had just copied and pasted the : classpath separator. But I tried what you said I am still getting the same error. Have you tried the example. Is it working for you?

Comment: If I create an environment user variable CLASSPATH with value '.' will it work?

Comment: @Bruce: I can't remember offhand whether specifying both CLASSPATH and -cp will combine the two - I suspect not. I think it's best to just put it on the command line, or use an IDE so you don't need to do it manually all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're building the test correctly? Here are the steps you'll need to take:

1. Create a file named Test.java, because it will contain the class named Test
2. Paste the Java code from the *Getting Started* section into this file and save it
3. Download the sqlitejdbc-v056.jar file
   and put it in the same directory as the Test.java file
4. Use `javac` to compile Test.java into Test.class
5. Run the command from the *Getting Started* section

You should see:

```
name = Gandhi
job = politics
name = Turing
job = computers
name = Wittgenstein
job = smartypants
```

as output.

Comment: Indeed it is, hence the output.